# Create Generic method in generic repository consumer class

Tags: c#, generics

I want to create generic method in generic repository consumer class.

Here is my generic method in generic repository class:

```
public class CosmosDBRepository<T> : ICosmosDBRepository<T> where T : class
    {
     public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetItemsAsync(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByDesc, int takeCount = -1)
    
            {
                var criteria = _container.GetItemLinqQueryable<T>(true)
                    .Where(predicate)
                    .OrderByDescending(orderByDesc)
                    .ToFeedIterator();
    
                var query = criteria;
    
                var results = new List<T>();
                while (query.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    if (takeCount > -1 && results.Count >= takeCount) break;
                    results.AddRange(await query.ReadNextAsync());
                }
    
                return results;
            }
}
```

Generic Repository consumer class:

```
 public class SubscriptionRepository : CosmosDBRepository<Subscription>, ISubscriptionRepository
    {
        public SubscriptionRepository(
            ICosmosDBClient client
            ) : base(client)
        {

        }

        
        public async Task<List<T>> GetSubscriptions<T, TE>(
            TE eventItem,
            params SubscriptionAction[] subscriptionAction)
                where T : Subscription
                where TE : Event
        {
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = (x) => x.EventType == eventItem.EventType
                            && x.IsActive;

            predicate = predicate.And(x => subscriptionAction.Contains(x.Action));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventItem.PayerNumber))
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(x => x.PayerNumber == eventItem.PayerNumber);
            }
            else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(eventItem.AccountNumber))
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(x => x.AccountNumber == eventItem.AccountNumber);
            }

            var result = await GetItemsAsync(predicate, o => o.PayerNumber);

            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Now I want to create generic method `GetSubscriptions` in `SubscriptionRepository` class.

Could you please suggest how I can achieve this?

Currently I am getting following compile time error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expression<System.Func<T,bool>>' to
> 'System.Linq.Expression.Expression<System.Func<FleetHub.Notifications.Domain.CosmosDB.Containers.Subscription,bool>>'

Comment: What is the issue ? You want that method to appears in the interface ? You will have to create a new interface, specialized for the subscriptions repository.

Comment: @Arcord, Currently I am getting compile time error "cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expression<System.Func<T,bool>>' to 'System.Linq.Expression.Expression<System.Func<FleetHub.Notifications.Domain.CosmosDB.Containers.Subscription,bool>>'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two issues here, both of the same nature - you trying to make a generic method to wrap a concrete `CosmosDBRepository<Subscription>.GetItemsAsync` function. First one can be solved changing predicate to:

```
Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>> predicate = x => x.EventType == eventItem.EventType && x.IsActive;
```

But it will not solve issue that `CosmosDBRepository<Subscription>.GetItemsAsync` will return collection of `Subscription`'s and not collection of arbitrary `Subscription` descendant. If you need `GetSubscriptions` still be generic you will need either to filter and cast result of `GetItemsAsync`:

```
return result.OfType<T>().ToList();
```

Or provide a mapper function to method:

```
 public async Task<List<T>> GetSubscriptions<T, TE>(
        TE eventItem,
        Func<Subscription, T> mapper, 
        params SubscriptionAction[] subscriptionAction)
            where T : Subscription
            where TE : Event
    {
        .....
        return result.Select(mapper).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried result.OfType<T>().Cast<T>().ToList();but it returned 0

Comment: @RakeshKumar the means there is no instances of  `T` type returned by `GetSubscriptions`. Which, TBH is not that strange

Comment: Could you please suggest with example how Can I achieve this with mapper?

Comment: @RakeshKumar you provide a lambda expression which builds your `T` from Subscription. Like `s => new ConcreteT { Field1 = s.SomeField1, Field2 = s.SomeField2, ... }`

Comment: Do I need to create a custom mapper than I have to pass that method as parameter?

Comment: @RakeshKumar yes, that is idea.

Comment: Thanks! a million Guru Stron. Just one more question. I have 10-12 Concrete Types which all have similar properties except the NotificationType. So Is there any possibilities to create a generic mapper? So that i can reduce some duplicate code.

Comment: @RakeshKumar was glad to help! If they are inherited from the same base class (I assume yes, `Subscription`) and have properties with accessible setters you can create something like `FillFromSubscription<T>(Subscription source, T target) where T: Subscription { // copy properties here }`

Comment: But I am facing problem to initialize the properties for T type from this generic method. Could you please some concrete example?

Comment: As you suggested how Can I access Field, Field2 of type T properties in my generic method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216381/discussion-between-guru-stron-and-rakesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use

```
Expression<Func<Subscription, bool>> predicate = (x) => x.EventType == eventItem.EventType
                        && x.IsActive;
```

Since you are using a generic type T instead of Subscription (even if you check that T is supposed to be Subscription or a child class) the expression cannot be assigned.

And in your case I don't see the benefits to use generic in the GetSubscriptions instead of the real type directly.

Check this example :

```
   public class Test
   {
   }

   Expression<Func<Test, bool>> temp1 = (t) => true;
   Expression<Func<object, bool>> temp2 = temp1;
```

This example will fail at the second line. Even is Test is a child class of object (as all class in .NET)

**Edit**

As explained here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netcore-3.1

The T of Func (the first generic type parameter) have the "in" keyword. Which means :

> This type parameter is contravariant. That is, you can use either the
> type you specified or any type that is less derived.

Since T could be a child of Subscription (let's say "ChildSubscription").
When you try to assign Func to Func your try to assign a more derived.